# How do I amend an existing javascript to display currency values including cents?

Tags: php, javascript, currency, decimal

A site I'm working on (which I inherited...I don't know javascript that well) has code currently set up to display ".00" at the end of any number in the database (a PHP include page, actually) such that it displays as currency on an online form.

My client now wants to add an amount to the list which includes cents ($5.50), and I need help modifying or amending the script so I can include these non-whole currency amounts.

Here is the snippet of the script that (I think/presume) addresses the currency formatting:

```
function CurrencyFormatted(amount)
{
    var i = parseFloat(amount);
    if(isNaN(i)) { i = 0.00; }
    var minus = '';
    if(i < 0) { minus = '-'; }
    i = Math.abs(i);
    i = parseInt((i + .005) * 100);
    i = i / 100;
    s = new String(i);
    if(s.indexOf('.') < 0) { s += '.00'; }
    if(s.indexOf('.') == (s.length - 2)) { s += '0'; }
    s = minus + s;
    return s;
}
```

Is there a way to add to or change this code so that I can display the specific cents needed for this one (and future similar) amounts?

Answer (score 3):

That code is doing some interesting rounding things, which I can't really address, but to format a number with a fixed number of digits to the right of the decimal, use the [`toFixed`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.4.5) function on numbers:

```
var n = 1.2345;
n.toFixed(2); // "1.23"
```

Note that it does rounding, so:

```
(1.234).toFixed(2); // "1.23"
(1.235).toFixed(2); // "1.24"
```

(You don't need the parens when you're calling `toFixed` on a variable, but you do need them when calling it on a literal as I did in the two examples above. Naturally, in your case, you'll be using a variable so no need for them.)

---

Re your comment/question below:

> Thanks for the quick replies! I guess I should have said I don't know javascript AT ALL, so my questions are: 1) where do I insert the codes you offer above into my existing code...

1) The code you quoted in your question is doing a bunch of operations on the number fed into it, including adding half a cent to it before trying to round it to two digits (in a very non-optimal way). If the goal now is to faithfully reproduce a rounded-to-two-digits version of the number fed in (none of this adding half-a-cent stuff), you can replace the entire function with this:

```
function CurrencyFormatted(amount)
{
    return parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2);
}
```

If you want to continue adding half a cent to it:

```
function CurrencyFormatted(amount)
{
    return (parseFloat(amount) + 0.005).toFixed(2);
}
```

> ...and 2) will this allow all of my existing other numbers to continue displaying as they are (e.g. "25" in my include file displays as "25.00")?

Any number (or numeric string) you feed into the above will be formatted with two digits to the right of the decimal, even if those digits are `00`. So with the above, `CurrencyFormatted("25")` will return `"25.00"`.

> ...Or do I use this code you suggest to replace part or all of the sample code I posted, and thus, would I then need to change all my database numbers to accommodate this? (i.e. should I add two zeros to the end of all my whole numbers now? (25 becomes 2500, etc.)

You don't need to add `.00` to whole numbers in the database or anything like that.

Comment: or, as a drop-in replacement, `function CurrencyFormatted(amount) { return (parseFloat(amount) || 0).toFixed(2); }`

Comment: @Kevin: I didn't try to follow all the logic in that function around things like `i = parseInt((i + .005) * 100);` I left that part as an exercise for Bryan. :-) Also, I wasn't at all sure he wasn't planning to ditch it now that he's showing actual cents values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! I guess I should have said I don't know javascript AT ALL, so my questions are: 1) where do I insert the codes you offer above into my existing code, and 2) will this allow all of my existing other numbers to continue displaying as they are (e.g. "25" in my include file displays as "25.00")? Or do I  use this code you suggest to replace part or all of the sample code I posted, and thus, would I then need to change all my database numbers to accommodate this? (i.e. should I add two zeros to the end of all my whole numbers now? (25 becomes 2500, etc.)

Comment: @BryanDechter: Updated to try to answer those questions.

Comment: Thanks. So, to clarify, if I want to display "$5.50" in my form, what should the database/include file have, so the cents display properly?

Comment: @BryanDechter: Without seeing the PHP file, obviously I can't say. But whatever it is that's feeding values through the JavaScript function you've described, just has to pass numbers through it. (And if you want a `$`, you'll have to adjust the above to put that, e.g., add `"$" + ` after `return` and before what follows the `return`.)

Comment: Below is the code from the PHP include file, which feeds the forms the amounts. As you can see, the previous programmer set it up so that these numbers display in the form with the decimal and "00" added to the end (I think in a different table cell, actually). The fourth item in the second section (uk_firstaid_courier) is the new item that needs to display as 5.50, rather than the ".00" added to all the other prices. I have it set to 6 right now, until I can solve this issue. Does this help you to help me, or does this look I need to completely revamp the code and PHP files?

Comment: I guess it's too many characters to paste here. Here's just the part that includes the price at issue (courier):

Comment: //----------------------------------------------
//   First Aid Homeopathy Courses
//----------------------------------------------
define ( 'uk_firstaid_reg_fee', 0 );
define ( 'uk_firstaid_reg_complete', 149 );
define ( 'uk_firstaid_reg_basic', 99 );
define ( 'uk_firstaid_courier', 6 );

Comment: T.J., I think your suggestion worked! Thanks! I just entered "5.5" in my PHP file, and it added the needed zero. All the other whole number prices kept their ".00" too. I am most grateful!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted todo this with PHP checkout [money_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) heres an example:

```
<?php 
$value = 5;

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo '$'.money_format('%i', $value) . "\n";//$5.00


$value = 5.545;

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo '$'.money_format('%i', $value) . "\n";//$5.54

$value = 9.99;

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo '$'.money_format('%i', $value) . "\n";//$9.99

?>
```